# Privacy - Microphone Usage Description permission not appear in iOS 10.3.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios10.3.2

Currently I am developing audio recording app which record the audio hence I set microphone permission in info.plist file so record audion permission alert displaying in iOS 10.3.2 but its not appearing in iOS 10.3.3 devices .

[image]

Code to request permission

```
let session:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try session.overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSessionPortOverride.none)

        if (session.responds(to: #selector(AVAudioSession.requestRecordPermission(_:)))) {


            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({(granted: Bool)-> Void in
                if granted {
                    print("Permission to record granted")
                    self.setSessionPlayAndRecord()
                    if setup {
                        self.setupRecorder()
                    }

                    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
                    self.recorder?.record()

                } else {
                    print("Permission to record not granted")
                }
            })
        } else {
            print("requestRecordPermission unrecognized")
        }


        //Start Record 
       /* self.setSessionPlayAndRecord()
        if setup {
            self.setupRecorder()
        }

        UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
        self.recorder?.record()*/



    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Audio Session error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you requesting permission in code when you need mic?

Comment: @AntonioM question is updated plz check

Comment: Hi, i just test it in a iOS 10.3.3 and iOS 11.0 and it works fine. I test the your request permission code. Did you check that you call this code? Use breakpoints also.

Comment: I resolved issue someone restrict location in iPad devices

Comment: @AntonioM Thanks for support !!!